# what is the php code for retrieving file sent using windows phone 8 Restsharp

Tags: c#, php, wordpress, windows-phone, restsharp

here is the restsharp code, please help me with the php code that retrieves the file sent, if it is sent in the first place, i really don't know. and please can you tell if my c# code is correct and that its really sending the file or not. the code sends the parameter successfully but for the file i don't know, i cant tell until i have a solid php code that can handle the request. i took the code from http://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/uploading-files-to-remote-server-with-multiple-parameters/
Regards And thanks

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CameraCaptureTask cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraCapture.Completed += cameraCapture_Completed;
        cameraCapture.Show();
    }
    private void cameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
            return;

        string userId = tb.Text;

        //preparing RestRequest by adding server url, parameteres and files...
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("http://server/page.php", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("id", userId);
        request.AddFile("image", ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto), "photo.jpg", "image/pjpeg");


        //calling server with restClient
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //upload successfull
                MessageBox.Show("Upload completed succesfully...\n" +      response.Content);
            }
            else
            {
                //error ocured during upload
                MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode + "\n" + response.StatusDescription);
            }
        });
    }
    public byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        long originalPosition = stream.Position;
        stream.Position = 0;

        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                {
                    int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                    if (nextByte != -1)
                    {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                        readBuffer = temp;
                        totalBytesRead++;
                    }
                }
            }

            byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
            if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
            {
                buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Position = originalPosition;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP side you can use the following code (this would be the content of page.php) to check what the server has received:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';

// show details of file(s) sent to page.
var_dump($_FILES);

// show details of parameters POSTed to page.
var_dump($_POST);

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

This allows you to check that *something* has happened from the c# side.

If you can't view the server output directly you can output to a file (details.txt) in the same folder on the server as page.php using this code instead:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('details.txt', print_r($_FILES, true) . "\n" . print_r($_POST, true));

?>
```

You should read up on the [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and [handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) in PHP.